# Resset password bittorrent sync

Tags: sync

I've installed Bittorent Sync.
But typed the password wrong..

How can I resset the password of Bittorent Sync?

Ofc on ubuntu

Comment: I have exactly the same issue... In addition, seems like Chrome somehow remembers my wrong password and doesn't even give me the chance to type a different one (the one that I forgot...)